# How to write a query in android using contentResolver to get images of particular date only from gallery?

Tags: android

I want to write a query in android using contentResolver to get images of particular date only from gallery?

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
 Cursor imagecursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, null);
```

This gives me all the images,I want images of particular date and particular time.Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly query image from date itself `MediaStore` understand timestamp only. so if you want an image of particular date you must first convert that date into timestamp like following.

```
//converting date to timestamp
public static long getTimeStamp(String calculatedDate) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = null;

    try {
        date = formatter.parse(calculatedDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long output = 0;
    if (date != null) {
        output = date.getTime() / 1000L;
    }
    String str = Long.toString(output);
    return Long.parseLong(str) * 1000;
}
```

you now need to query this with timestamp like following.here you need to pass two timestamp that match images greater than given date and less than next date. so you need exact output as you want.

```
cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + ">=? and " + MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + "<=?", new String[]{"" + givendate_timestamp, "" + nextdate_timestamp}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

Comment: cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + "=?", new String[]{"" + givendate_timestamp}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");                     wont this work,passing the exact date

Comment: Thanks for your help.Is there a way i can get image of particu;ar time period only for that particular date?

Comment: @stackLearner  please check updated query.. it takes second parameter as String array.  and yes my friend this works great for me.. the timestamp converter works like this. suppose we take date 22-11-2016 so it gives you timestamp of 22-11-2016 and time 00:00:00 so this states the starting timestamp of the date. and we also input next day timestamp so it would be 23-11-2016 and time of 00:00:00. so in our query >= givendate_timestamp and <=nextdate_timestamp. hope you got it.

Comment: If i want image of  22-11-2016 12:30:45 to 22-11-2016 16:30:45,this query is returning null. data Formatter is  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:yy"); And I am passing calculated date like 22-11-2016 12:30:45

Comment: Thanks alot,ur explanation helped a lot.Thanks once again

Comment: @stackLearner your formation needs to correct it should be DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:yy"); HH represents hours in 0-24.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN};

String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";
```

for more [How to make sort gallery thumbnails image by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745521/how-to-make-sort-gallery-thumbnails-image-by-date)

Comment: i dont want to order them,i want to get images of particular date only

Comment: which means are giving the date as your input or else you want to image were created date

Comment: image created date, I am not giving any input