# Getting location of the images in android?

Tags: java, android, exif, geotagging

I am making an android application that displays all the images of the gallery location wise. I am unsure of the ExifData if it can help me in sorting the images, location wise. Any guidance along with the necessary code will be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745521/how-to-make-sort-gallery-thumbnails-image-by-date check this out

Comment: I want it location wise 
It's like I want to create folders of different locations and have pictures in them.